# 'f was unexpected at this time.' error while attempting to recursively bulk rename S3 files from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am attempting to bulk rename thousands of S3 files based on a string find and replace pattern using AWS CLI. Within my S3 bucket, test-bucket, I have the following files:

```
ph_20210827_181500.txt
ph_20210827_183000.txt
```

As a test, I want to rename the files to:

```
test_20210827_181500.txt
test_20210827_183000.txt
```

So I opened a command prompt, entered "aws configure sso", and then following [this blog post here](http://gerardvivancos.com/2016/04/12/Single-and-Bulk-Renaming-of-Objects-in-Amazon-S3/), entered the following code:

```
for f in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket test-bucket --prefix "" --delimiter "/" | grep ph | cut -f 3); do aws s3 mv s3://test-bucket/$f s3://test-bucket/${f/ph/test}; done
```

This threw an error:

```
f was unexpected at this time.
```

I have seen [posts](https://superuser.com/questions/770127/f-f-was-unexpected-at-this-time) about replacing %f with %%f, but I don't see where I would make that replacement. I have triple-checked the syntax. I can confirm that the quotes are not stylized. And I've confirmed that I do have AWS access. I'm not sure what else to try or how t debug this. Any thoughts on what else I can try?

**Update:**
I was previously entering this on a Windows command prompt. I just tried Windows PowerShell and it provided some clarification on the error:

```
At line:1 char:4
+ for f in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket test-bucket --prefix ""  ...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:1 char:111
+ ... -bucket --prefix "" --delimiter "/" | grep ph | cut -f 3); do aws s3  ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing statement body in do loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

Is there a syntax change that will make this work on a Windows command prompt? Or is there a recommendation for a good bash shell in Windows that works well with AWS CLI?

Comment: I got this command working fine. what shell are you using?

Comment: Are you using Window or some Unix platform?

Comment: I was using a windows command prompt. Is there something else I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, it should be (s3 command modified):

```
for f in $(aws s3api list-objects --bucket test-bucket --prefix "" --delimiter "/" --query "Contents[].Key" --output text | grep "ph"); do
    aws s3 mv s3://test-bucket/$f s3://test-bucket/${f/ph/test} 
done
```

Comment: No luck with this - it threw the same error.